# Ajax call not working as expected in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails application I have this code

```
<a data-remote="true" href="#" class: "find_product">Find product</a>
```

For ajax call I am doing this

```
$(document).on('click', '.find_product', function(){     
              $.ajax({
                     url: "<%= startup_wizard_find_horse_path() %>",
                    dataType: 'script',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { box_no: "3"}
            });
            return false;


        });
```

Now when I click on the above link ajax call is sent to the current page action not to the

```
startup_wizard_find_horse_path
```

Why this is happening and how can I make this work?

Comment: I might not know Rails, so at the risk of getting flogged: WTF is `class: "find_product"`?

Comment: And one more thing, learn to use the **[Network Tab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572)** if you want to avoid hours of hair-pulling

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use data-remote, set the href value and don't define a click event, that's the point of unobtrusive JS in Rails.

If you want to use jQuery manually, remove the `remote = true` and change your jQuery click to this, to disable the default behavior of the link:

```
$(document).on('click', '.find_product', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= startup_wizard_find_horse_path() %>",
    dataType: 'script',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { box_no: "3"}
  });
  return false;
});
```

EDIT: Here's a post that recaps how to use remote links: [link_to and remote => true + jquery : How? Help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052650/link-to-and-remote-true-jquery-how-help)

Comment: when I remove this part data: { box_no: "3"} from ajax call this work just fine

Comment: You're still mixing two different approaches, your remote link is pointless if you're not defining the URL and writing custom jQuery.

Comment: What error do you get in your JS console? in your Rails log? Is the URL rendered properly in your JS output? What does your `startup_wizard_find_horse` method look like?