# Rails AJAX rails-ujs reference is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am experimenting with Rails and the AJAX helper - `remote: true`. I have a view with a link:

```
<%= link_to 'My Profile', edit_user_path(current_user), class: 'user-profile', remote: true %>
```

This fires an AJAX request to a controller:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render plain: "Test" }
    end
  end
```

Which returns "Test" to my js ajax listener:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  $('.user-profile').on('ajax:success', function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    let data = response.detail[0]
    $('.profile-content').append(data)
  });

  $('.user-profile').on('ajax:error', function(event) { console.log(response) })

})
```

Everything works as expected. "Test" is appended ( I have also appended views and JSON objects). However, whenever I get a response back, I get a JS error in my console:
[image]

If I render an HTML view then I get:

[image]

What could be causing this? Its driving me mad because everything works as expected but I get an error.

Comment: Use the json format instead, like `format.json { render json: { data: 'Test' } }`, note the json sent from the controller is a hash which you'll have to parse.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Any idea why just rendering plain text would cause an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you try by parsing the received data when sending a plain text?

Comment: I did not. I will give it a try now, but I think you're right. I'm guessing JS processor doesn't know the response format without me explicitly defining it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, if you get a conclusion, you can answer and accept your own question.

Comment: Not related to the question itself, but you shouldn't send `current_user` as a parameter to the edit method. instead just use `@user = User.find(current_user.id)` in the edit method itself. otherwise people could edit the html code and send whichever user id they want.

Comment: That’s what I was wondering when I set it up, but if a user has to login to use the edit form, then wouldn’t that allow me to use current_user instead of User.find ? To reduce database hits, that why I used current_user since it’s cached and it’s the object I need to edit.

Comment: I am reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052650/link-to-and-remote-true-jquery-how-help#8673600

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio that link is helpful. thank you.